# Wrong Time in Calender.getTime() method

Tags: java

I have a problem in getting time from the Calender object 
I have a method like the below one to return the current time as String but the retuned time is not right

```
public static String getCreatedDate()
{
    String createdDate = null;
    String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"; 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    createdDate= sdf.format(cal.getTime());        

    System.out.println(createdDate);
    return createdDate;
}
```

the date/time returned from the method is 2013-06-02T **08:18:09.68** but the right time should be **10:18:09.68** ... the method returns time shifted back 2 hours ....

Comment: Are you looked your system time? In BIOS.

Comment: Sounds like time zones being set incorrectly.

Comment: Guess you are now in a place with a time zone of GMT +2, as @Thilo says.

Comment: Thanks ....Right ... I am in a zone which has GMT+2 ... but I think that calender should return my local time as I don't want to set the time zone

Comment: Time zone is probably wrong dude below explained.

Comment: @egy: Date and Calendar are very bad APIs. It's very hard to use them properly due to problems like yours. In Java 8 a new API will be released, but for the moment, if you are going to use dates intensively, I would suggest to use Joda Time, a very nice API: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `TimeZone` on the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Pacific"));
```

To find available `TimeZone` values you could make a simple test like this:

```
for(String s : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
{
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

To check your current default `TimeZone` value:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

EDIT: My previous answer (setting the Locale on the Calendar) was not tested and not working (see comment of JB Nizet).

Comment: How would it change the current time, or the way the DateFormat formats the current time? The Calendar is irrelevant in the question. The OP might as well use `sdf.format(new Date())`